# Main Service Panel - Outdoor/200 amps

Tags: meter

I am trying to do is pick out a service panel. MY requirements are. Meter on the Left, 4 jaw Ring, no bypass, outdoor, surface mount, 200 amp, Main Breaker, 8 breaker spaces Underground feed and Lower Right Side knockout. What are the requirement I should be looking for in a unit. Is breaker type just preference or is one better then the other. Is Bolt on better for outside use, versus Plug on. I will install a 100amp breaker and feed to an RV panel on same board. It has it's own breakers for 50/30/20amp plugs.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. If outside the panel will need a 3R rating or better.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I updated the question.

Comment: Who is your utility?

Comment: Pud3 Hoodsport wa

Answer (score 1):

It’s up to you whether to get a combo meter-main-panel it get them as separates.  I prefer a separate meter from panel, so You can change the panel without having the PoCo come out and remove the service drop (and all the permits and inspections they will require for that).

A “farm panel” is a popular product that contains 8 breaker spaces **and thru-lugs** for carrying the full 200A onward to another panel.  That seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: If I need ever need to change the panel, i would be because I have built a house and it would have to be changed anyway, baring it failing. But it's a nice easy simple installation with the combo. I don't want to have to pay an electrician to wire up the whole setup. Just the service wires to the meter and from my 100 amp breaker in service panel to RV panel 6inches away. So, as long as it's rated for outdoors it does not matter which one?

Comment: @Dean it's an outdoor panel, What we see a lot of is either those rusting out, or going obsolete and you find yourself in a pinch to find breakers. "This is all I'll ever need" are 'famous last words': we see a lot of people needing to add circuits to full panels.  Any of the Big Four (Square D, Eaton, Siemens, GE) make perfectly competent panels.  Of course CH and QO are "industrial grade" with better support and copper bus bars. HOMeline is the shoemaker's son, with the worst support.  Not even a 60A GFCI, give me a break. Siemens handles generator interlocks particularly well.

Comment: And actually with a farm panel, you wouldn't need to *change* the panel, just grab the "thru lugs" on the bottom and carry them onward to the new house.  That's what farm panels are designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

### I'd use an all-in-one pedestal unit

As it turns out, you can get everything you need (200A 4-jaw ringstyle meter socket, support for underground service), 50/30/20A RV receptacles, and room for an onwards feed or branch breaker spaces) in a single piece of hardware: the Midwest Electric M275CP6010.  While it doesn't stake a claim to having an EUSERC standard pull section, it shouldn't pose too much trouble for your utility, and has 4 spaces left over that can be used to feed other things.  (If you wanted to feed a panel, you could rearrange things and use a Midwest CB2200B or GE THLK2200 in the freed-up slots; for smaller panels or branch circuits, you can just use a THQL as a feeder breaker instead.)